# Jquery drag and drop ?How to make the drag div fixed

Tags: jquery

Link to the code -[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/GheD5/35/)

```
var makeDrag = function(){
    $("#hello").draggable({
        stop: function(){
            alert("Done dragging");

            $("#hello").draggable("destroy");

            var copy = $("#hello").clone(true);
            $("body").append(copy);
            copy.html("DRAG");
            copy.draggable();
            copy.css("left","120px");
            copy.css("top","140px");

            makeDrag();
        }
    });
}

makeDrag();

<div id="hello">DRAG</div>//THIS DIV SHOULD BE FIXED IN THE SAME POSITION
```

I am able to drag and drop but i the div hello to be fixed ? how to achieve this? For eg [**EXAMPLE LINK**](http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/1/dragghost)

Comment: div id=hello should be fixed and not to be altered should be in the same position....something as shown in the example link

Answer (score 1):

Use `helper: "clone"` option.

```
$("#hello").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function(){ 
      //existing stuff
    }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GheD5/36/)

Comment: Its cloning the multiple divs but all clone div are overlapped.

Comment: The code was to fixed the div. Although @dude i am not getting what do you mean by multiple clone div? When you dragging the div its cloning itself and append it to in body. and the code is working fine. do you need something else?

Comment: hmmm ya... @kundan singh chouhan.. here is my full code!!! please check the link!!! http://jsfiddle.net/GheD5/40/   in this link i need the symbols to be clone to the colour which i select...which is similar to the question